# Cannot wrap Blazor InputSelect in component, incorrect binding pass through?

Tags: blazor

I am trying to enhance the Blazor 8 user registration component with a langauge selection dropdown.

The following code works fine:

```
<InputSelect 
    class="form-select"
    @bind-Value="Input.LanguageIsoCode">
    @foreach (Language lang in LanguageUtil.Languages)
    {
        <option value="@lang.IsoCode">@lang.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

I'd now like to componetize this, so I can re-use it elsewhere in my app.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<LanguageSelect @bind-Value="Input.LanguageIsoCode"/>
```

I've tried this:

```
<InputSelect 
    class="form-select"
    @bind-Value="Value"
    @bind-Value:after="() => ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value)">
    @foreach (Language lang in LanguageUtil.Languages)
    {       
        <option value="@lang.IsoCode">@lang.Name</option>                    
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

**The value is set correctly but the change isn't propagated back unless I set "@rendermode InteractiveServer".  This breaks the registration page :(**

Is there another way to setup the binding so it works?  I guess my problem is how I'm passing through the binding-Value?

**Additional Info:**

The problem seems to be with the generated name attribute on the select tag.

Working:

```
<select name="Input.LanguageIsoCode" class="form-select valid" value="fr">
  <option value="aa">Afar</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Not working

```
<select name="Value" class="form-select valid" value="fr">
  <option value="aa">Afar</option>
  ...
</select>
```

If I change the name="Value" to the correct value it all works (seeing as this is a form post).  I guess my component will need to generate the name just like InputBase/InputSelect.

Comment: So what mode have you set the registration page to?

Answer (score 1):

My guess at `LanguageUtil`.

```cs
public static class LanguageUtil
{
    public static IEnumerable<Language> Languages = new List<Language>() {
        new ("UK", "United Kingdom"),
        new ("E", "Spain"),
        };
}

public readonly record struct Language(string IsoCode, string Name );
```

`LanguageSelect`:

```cs
<InputSelect class="form-select"
             @bind-Value:get="Value"
             @bind-Value:set="OnValueChanged">

    @if (this.Value == string.Empty)
    {
        <option selected disabled value=""> -- Please Select a Value -- </option>
    }

    @foreach (Language lang in LanguageUtil.Languages)
    {
        <option value="@lang.IsoCode">@lang.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(string value)
    {
        if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
            await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And a demo, using the standard get and set.  Note I've added a please select option for when the value is `string.Empty`, and separated the setter methos out for clarity: I don't believe in mixing execution code and markup code.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<LanguageSelect @bind-Value="_value" />

<div class="alert alert-primary mt-3"> @_value</div>

@code {
    private string _value = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this has the same problem.  I believe the issue is due to the rendermode.  The default register page uses SSR and a post action.

Comment: A thought:  Seeing as it's posting a form, the field names need to be set.  When you bind a field without setting a name, blazor seems to generate it with a matching name. I'll look at the generated HTML and see what's different.

Comment: I assume you mean Static SSR.  You can't use active edit components within a static form.   There's no active stuff to handle the bind callback from the component and update the value in the static form.

Comment: To point to my original post, it works when it's not inside my own component.  And surely InputSelect is a component itself?

Comment: Updated info above.   I see that InputSelect uses InputBase that does some extra work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was creating an intermediatry binding to Value that broke the InputSelect name generation.

The following code passes through all the binding info and works correctly:

```
@using Playsemble.Util
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<InputSelect 
    class="form-select"
    Value="@Value"
    ValueChanged="@ValueChanged"
    ValueExpression="@ValueExpression">
    @foreach (Language lang in LanguageUtil.Languages)
    {       
        <option value="@lang.IsoCode">@lang.Name</option>                    
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<string>> ValueExpression { get; set; } = default;
}
```